# How to handle special characters in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

[image]

"St. Josephs Healthcare Hamilton", could see that this special character is coming from various data sources(Oracle) to my database (SQL Server 2008 R2).

Verified in Oracle source system and it is correct over there:

```
"St. Joseph's Healthcare Hamilton"
```

Updated the string in SQL Server with "St. Joseph's Healthcare Hamilton". but there are lot of incoming strings coming on daily with ****

Can any body tell me how to fix this issue to store proper value in the SQL Server table? "St. Joseph's Healthcare Hamilton"

This is the work around I am currently using, but I need to find a permanent fix.

```
INSERT INTO Person (First, Last)
VALUES ('Joe', 'O''Brien')
```

We are pulling data via SQL Server Agent, there is a stored procedure which will pull the data from Oracle and will insert into staging tables.

Comment: Add detail to you question as to how data are being copied from Oracle to SQL Server. The problem and solution probably is in that process.

Comment: When you are getting data from Oracle, whether it is stored into variables or in temp tables or anywhere else? If the data are coming from Oracle then you might not be inserting the way you are inserting in question.

Answer (score 0):

As per requirement

```
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

    INSERT INTO Person(First, Last)
    VALUES('Joe', "O'Brein")

    Select * from Person
```

After your concern done you can SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

[image]